# Why is $f'(c) = \text{does not exist}$ a critical point?

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

In my lecture the prof wrote that when the derivative does not exist at a point it is also a critical point

I can understand that $f'(c) = 0$ indicates that we have a flat place on our curve, so $f(x)$ is constant there and it is a max or a min, but why is when the derivative not exist also a critical point?

Comment: What's the definition of a critical point? A point where the derivative doesn't exist might be a local maximum or local minimum, so if a critical point is one that might be a local extremum, it fits.

Comment: For example: $f(x) = x^{2/3}$ attains a minimum at its only critical point, $x = 0$.

Comment: I think the use of critical here is in the sense that the derivative has a sign change. Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$. The derivative to the left of $0$ is positive and to the right of $0$ is negative.

Comment: the question is what do want the critical points to have or tell you about the function? what is critical/special about the point? once you know what the critical points ought to do, you can find the conditions for a point to be critical.

Comment: "I can understand that f′(c)=0 indicates that we have a flat place on our curve, so f(x) is constant there and it is a max or a min" No, there need not be a flat place, $f$ need not be a constant there, and no it need not be either a max nor a min.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of a critical point as a "good candidate" for a point at which a local extremum could occur. To come up with a sensible way of formalizing this, think about common places where local extrema occur: for, say, $f(x)=x^2$, it's where $f'(x)=0$, but for $g(x)=|x|$, it's where $g'(x)$ is undefined (i.e. at $x=0$). We also want a critical point of a function $f(x)$ to be in the domain of $f(x)$, e.g. to avoid calling $0$ a critical point of a function like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$: $f'(x)$ is certainly undefined at $x=0$, but $f(0)$ could never be a local extremum as it's not even defined to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Where does the function $|x|$ attain it's minimum? Where does $\sqrt[3]{x}$ change concavity?